# Como fazer para um Custom Attribute em uma webapi obter o parâmetro passado via Url C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou criando um Custom Attribute em uma webapi para validação de um valor e gostaria de saber se tem como capturar esse valor vindo de uma requisição GET.

Eu queria fazer dessa forma:

```
[Validacao]
public Empresa consularEmpresa([FromUri]string codigo){}
```

Sem precisar passar isso:

```
[Validacao("codigo")]
public Empresa consultaEpresa([FromUri]string codigo){}
```

Código da Validação:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class NfeValidation:ValidationAttribute
{
    public Validacao(string chave)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chave) && chave.Length == 44)
        {
            string modeloNF = chave.Substring(18,2);
            if(modeloNF != "55")
            {
                new HttpException("Modelo de nota fiscal inválido!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isso ai acima é o meu contexto de exemplo do que queria fazer.

Por exemplo, preciso validar uma chave de acesso passado no meu webapi via url e verificar se a mesma esta com os 44 dígitos e se o modelo é 55 mais primeiro o meu (Attribute ou ValidationAttribute) deve validar essa regra antes de executar o meu método

Comment: Como é o código de `Validacao` ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
    public class ValidationNF:ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        var descriptor = actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
                            + " - " + actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        var header = actionContext.Request.Headers;
        string erro = "";
```

}}

E consigo pegar o dado e validar antes de chamar o método.
A chamada ficou dessa forma exatamente o que eu queria:

```
    [ValidationNF]
public class ConsultaNFController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public Empresa ConsultaNfe([FromUri]string chave)
    {
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        return empresa;
    }
}
```

Agora vou tratar o que preciso, obrigado assim mesmo;)

Comment: É isso mesmo. É uma boa abordagem